# inflate (decompress) a datastream on an embedded device

Tags: c, embedded, inflate

I am intending to use a compression for a data stream transmitted over a slow serial interface.
The decompression should take place on a low cost microcontroller with limited resources (no os, no threads, limited ram).

In a similar configuration before, I used zlib's puff.c, but in that case a had a buffer storing all the data before and could inflate all at once.

In my actual case I don't have enough memory for those kind of buffer, so I need to inflated the data coming step by step.
So instead of having puff working on a buffer I would need to able calling it each time new datas are arriving, keeping the internal states between subsequent calls.

Before I start deep diving into zlib or zlibs puff.c, does anybody know if these kind of problem has already been solved somewhere?

Comment: Does it needs to be compressed on the fly, or could be compressed offline, before sending?

Comment: "Find a library" questions are off-topic on SO and besides you have already found it: ZLIB uses a stream interface and is entirely capable of inflating a stream using small buffers.  The ZLIB usage example at https://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html shows exactly how to inflate a stream using a fixed size buffer - the example uses 16Kb but it can be smaller (set `CHUNK` size).  The full code is at https://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c.

Answer (score 0):

The [.GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) file format compression algorithm ([LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch), a variant of LZ78) pretty much only needs to maintain a hash table in memory. When the table fills up, it's emptied, and the process repeats, meaning the table doesn't grow indefinitely. There's no need to keep around the compressed data either. Very little of other state needs to be maintained. With an algorithm like that (perhaps, with reduced hash table size) you can decompress data as it comes in.

I haven't looked into other LZ algorithms, but I expect (some or all of?) them to be similar in nature.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [LZSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski). I used [code](http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/compression/lzss.c) from [Haruhiko Okumura](http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/) as base. It uses the last portion of uncompressed data(2K) as dictionary. The code I linked can be modified to use almost no memory if you have all the uncompressed data available in memory. With a bit of Googling you will find that a lot of different implementations with all kinds of licenses.

Another option could be the [lzfx](http://code.google.com/p/lzfx/) lib that implement LZF. I have not used it yet but it seems nice. Also uses previous results so it has low memory requirements and is released under a BSD Licence.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your comments and suggestions.

After investigation I will either stick to the puff.c and modify it 
or I will use the uzlib which I found here:
https://github.com/pfalcon/uzlib/